# Redireccionar utulizador a uma certa hora

Tags: php, javascript

Boa noite a todos, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de por exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte tabela na minha base de dados:

> table.videos

```
id | starttime

1  | 12:00
```

e passado duas horas meia, ou seja às 14:30 automaticamente o user é redireccionado para outra página..

Ex: o user está na pagina videos.php e exactamente as 14:30 (ou seja, mais duas horas do que está definido na base de dados) o user é redireccionado automaticamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei um script comentado para você. Existem várias formas de fazer esse código ok? Esse é só um exemplo.

```
<?php 

    $start = "12:00";// essa é a variável que vem do banco de dados
    $next = explode(":",$start); //separa a hora dos minutos
    $hour = (int)$next[0] + 2; // adiciona 2 horas
    $go = $hour.":".$next[1]; // cria a variável final

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    var go = "<?php echo $go; ?>";
    // essa função verifica a cada 10 milisegundos se o horario final é = o horario presente
    var stat = setInterval(function(){ atualiza(go) }, 10);
    function atualiza(go){
        var data = new Date();   
        var now = data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes();
        // se for igual ou maior
        if(now >= go){
            window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com"; // redireciona
            clearInterval(stat);// limpa
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Como foi colocado nos comentários, para que o usuário não burle as regras, re-fiz o script com o php sempre resgatando as datas. Ou seja, ele será resgatado pelo servidor. Então ficaria assim:

```
<?php 

    /*
        a variável start terá que ter esse formato:
        0000/00/00 00:00 (ano/mes/dia hora:minutos)
        isso indicará a data e hora do inicio que o usuário começou a usar o serviço

    */

    $start = "2017/04/09 14:55";// essa é a variável que vem do banco de dados
    $go = date('Y/m/d H:i', strtotime('+ 2 hours 30 minutes', strtotime($start))); // cria a variável final com 2 horas e meia a mais

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    var go = "<?php echo $go; ?>";
    // essa função verifica a cada 10 segundos se o horario final é = o horario presente
    var stat = setInterval(function(){ atualiza(go) }, 10);
    function atualiza(go){
        var data = new Date();   
        var now = data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes();
        // se for igual
        if(now >= go){
            window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com"; // redireciona
            clearInterval(stat);// limpa
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: E 2h e 30 min? Não da para adicionar minutos?

Comment: e se o utilizador tiver uma hora diferente no seu computador? Afeta em algo?

Comment: da sim... vou alterar..

Comment: vou comentar sobre tudo isso.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado !

Comment: Ai está. Veja que a variável $start terá que ser definida naquele formato de data ok? Então você precisará alterar o banco de dados ou criar uma nova coluna. Abraço!

Comment: Nao esquece de aprovar a resposta se ela te ajudou.

Comment: desculpe, ontem não vim mais cá, vou aprovar e muito obrigado por tudo!